# Can I use "strong feeling" this way?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> What do you think, is it beautiful or not beautiful? –Sorry, I do not
>   have strong feeling for it.

I doubt the use of “strong feeling” is not perfectly right here, because to have strong feeling for something is equal to “to like something very much”. Usually, people like beautiful things, and dislike ugly things, but to answer the question about whether it is beautiful or not with “I like it or not like it” is a little bit question-begging.

Comment: I don't have any (strong) preferences.

Comment: Usually one would refer to having "a strong feeling" or "strong feelings" about/for something. The way you phrase it is not typical.

Comment: A more common response would be "I don't have a strong opinion" or "I don't have a strong opinion either way."

Answer (score 1):

You can't have "strong feeling" in this way, because *feeling* here is an ordinary noun. You must have *a feeling* or plural *feelings.* Fortunately, *strong feelings* is a set phrase.

An idiomatic conversation might be:

> What do you think? Is it beautiful or not?
>   I don't have strong feelings one way or the other.

Note the omission of the last "beautiful". It's implied in the *not;* you don't need to repeat it.

The respondent uses the set phrase "strong feelings". The feelings need to be qualified in some way, and "one way or the other" is a set phrase which refers to the two alternatives offered. You could say "I don't have strong feelings about it."

Note that *having feelings for* normally refers to some sort of affection. If you have feelings for someone, you are attracted to them. Having feelings for some **thing** might be misinterpreted. If the conversation was about a sheep, for example (a sheep might have a particularly beatific facial expression), you don't want to say you have feelings for it!